# Erro 'No numeric types to aggregate'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estou fazendo um programa com base em um arquivo `.csv`, mas quando eu executo o programa ocorre o erro `No numeric types to aggregate`.

Parte do arquivo:

```
datatime,app version,gender,money

02/09/2019,4,F,$7.43

07/25/2019,1,F,$14.66

01/01/2019,4,M,,$9.99

01/30/2019,5,M,$5.61

04/01/2019,4,F,$13.70

09/26/2019,5,M,$8.84
```

Meu código:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dados = pd.read_csv('./aplicativo.csv', sep = ',', parse_dates = ['datatime'])

dados['mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dados['datatime'], yearfirst = True).month

def media(m):

return pd.DataFrame(m.groupby('mes')['money'].mean()).reset_index()
ind = media(dados)

plt.title('titulo')

plt.plot(ind['mes'], ind['money'], color = 'b')

plt.xlabel('mes')

plt.ylabel('media de valor pago')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro ocorre pois você está tentando agregar uma string como se fosse uma variável numérica.

Você deve transformar a coluna money em valor numérico:

```
dados['money'] = dados['money'].str.replace('$','')
dados['money'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['money'], errors='coerce')
```

---

Código:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dados = pd.read_csv('./aplicativo.csv', sep = ',', parse_dates = ['datatime']) 
dados['mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dados['datatime'], yearfirst = True).month

dados['money'] = dados['money'].str.replace('$','')
dados['money'] = pd.to_numeric(dados['money'], errors='coerce')

def media(m):
    return pd.DataFrame(m.groupby('mes')['money'].mean()).reset_index()

ind = media(dados)

plt.title('titulo') 
plt.plot(ind['mes'], ind['money'], color = 'b') 
plt.xlabel('mes') 
plt.ylabel('media de valor pago') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Bela resposta! Acrescentando: o `errors='coerce'` irá colocar NaN para aqueles valores que não puderem ser convertidos. Outra possibilidade após remover o `$` seria `dados['money'] = dados['money'].astype(float, errors='ignore')`. Colocando `errors='ignore'` faria com que o valor, no caso de um erro de conversão, fosse o original. Ou seja, em caso de erro de conversão, não agregaria.

Comment: Show Paulo, obrigado pelo comentário! Grande abraço!!